# Has anyone found "submit statistical information"?

Tags: update-manager, 12.10

In most versions of Ubuntu I've used (including 12.04), there was a tab inside the settings of the update manager (now called software updater) that allowed you to submit statistical information. I can't find this anywhere in 12.10, and a dash search isn't finding anything either.

Has anyone found this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "Statistics"-Tab was marked as deprecated and removed in Ubuntu 12.10.

This happened because they've added **"Recommendations"** in Ubuntu 12.10
(https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SoftwareCenter/Recommendations)

it appearance in the Beta of Ubuntu 12.10 was even marked as a bug in launchpad and fixed with the release of the package software-properties-0.92.

Source: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-properties/+bug/1025436